# How can I calculate population of a country after many years in C++?

Tags: c++, debugging

Let n be the population of a country, each year, the population of that country will increase by m%, what is the population (rounded) of that country after k years?

This is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n, k;
    float m;
    cin >> n >> m >> k;

    for (int i = 1; i <= k; i++) {
        n += n * (m / 100);
    }

    int x = round(n);
    cout << x << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I think it's quite simple, but I don't know why my code didn't work.

Comment: What is the input for `n`, `m`, and `k`?  What output did you expect, and what did you actually get?

Comment: This is more of a math question  population  = population *  (1.06 ^ number of years). Find a function in the math library that can help you. And then do not mix integer and floating point numbers. So you might want to convert number_of_years to a float somewhere.

Comment: In each iteration `n`  is truncated to an integer. Next iteration accumulates this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code actually "works" as is, *if*:

1. The initial population is large enough that at least one whole person is added per year, and
2. You *want* to truncate off any partial population gains for the year rather than preserving them until they add up to a whole person.

If a population with 99 initial people grows at 1% per year, you'll see it as never growing, because `n` is an `int`, and therefore discards the decimal component of the population added each year (rounding down *every* year, instead of rounding off, or preserving the decimal component to produce an extra person when it grows to a whole person in a later year).

For an initial population of 1000, growing at 2% for 10 years, you get a semi-reasonable answer of 1214 after 10 years.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n, k;
    float m;
    cin >> n >> m >> k;

    for (int i = 1; i <= k; i++) {
        n += n * (m / 100);
    }

    int x = round(n);
    cout << x << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY1LDsIwDET3OcVIbFIKorDt5y5RGkpE41RpIiGhnr24H8CLsewZP@thOHdaz/PBku5Ta1BZP8ZglGvEf6edio9GiDRa6kDKmXFQ2mCMbSmEpQinLMkMbwGuZUEnPMt1uvdecWAbtCU0DVZxi3BoS/kAuRxa1LiW3KqaTdg8/2KXIuQ1yxHS4YJrUWQbdxK/zy8GBJ@olbSb2qeIqmKHxVDb7z@DiSkQilJM88ysAjdGfgA)

That said, it's low relative to how population growth is usually computed. If you preserved the partial people and only rounded off once at the end, e.g., changing `n` and `m` to `double` (or `float` for less precision), you would get a final answer of 1219 instead of 1214, which is "correct" according to the simpler all-in-one calculation of `1000 * 1.02 ** 10` (which gets `1218.99442`, rounding to `1219`), which you could achieve yourself in C++ using `std::pow` instead of a hand-written loop, and would get the answer with (likely) smaller errors and greater performance, replacing your entire loop with just:

```cpp
n *= std::pow(1 + m/100.0, k);
```

In short:

1. Repeated rounding (and especially repeated *truncation*) is usually a bad idea, as it compounds small errors into bigger ones, and
2. If you can replace a loop that performs small floating point operations with a single bulk floating point operation, you'll run faster and with less floating point precision loss

Comment: Feels almost weird to see "Use `std::pow`." in an answer after so many years of "Don't use `std::pow`."

Comment: @user4581301: I must have missed this. Why were people saying this? Quality of implementation issue? Performance? Issues with type correctness? Inconsistent behavior depending on hardware and whether or not it was compiled with `-ffast-math`? Something else?

Comment: @user4581301: It is *"Don't use `std::pow` to calculate power with **integer** numbers"*.

Comment: The large number of questions where the asker needs to go in the other direction. They want an integer and try to use `pow` to get it.

Comment: @user4581301: Ah, okay. Yeah, in this case, your base is in fact floating point, and the alternatives to floating point are pretty horrible, and the tiny imprecision introduced is generally irrelevant when the final result is being rounded back to integer (and it's not like a statistically average population growth that comes to `0.5` is really "wrong" whichever way it's rounded anyway), so it's fine.